# how to use ternary operator in html to change the color of div

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6

I have a `div` for which I need to change the background color according to the values. I'm able to change only 1 color but I need two colors based on my values.

```html
<div
  class="panel-heading"
  style="background-color:@(Model[0].status == "HIGH" ? "#CE352C" : "#008E00")"
>
```

I'm getting red while `status == "HIGH"` and I need yellow while `status == "LOW"`

Comment: The style attribute doesn't work like JavaScript. BTW you need JS -- CSS and HTML cannot do what you want AFAIK.

Comment: You can’t do this in CSS.

Comment: yes its not possible with only html,css, so he must be using javascript as he mention in his question that he is able to change one value  based on one condition and he seeks help for other condition

Answer (score -2):

You can write your ternary operator condition like this

```
(status == "HIGH") ? "red" : ((status == "LOW") ? "yellow" : "green"))
```

for better understanding this is what they are saying as sometimes ternary operators are hard to read.

```
if (status == "HIGH"){ "red" } elseif(status == "LOW"){ "yellow" } else{ "green" }
```

hope it helps

Comment: <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: @(Model[10].status == "HIGH" ? "red": Model[10].status == "LOW" ? "yellow":"green")">

i tried like this but its not working, can u tell me why ?